# use css to hide unwrapped text node

Tags: html, css

```
<p class="entry-meta"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2017-06-03T02:58:22+00:00">June 3, 2017</time> by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a href="http://example.com/author/Albert/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author" target="_self"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Albert</span></a></span> <span class="entry-comments-link"><a href="http://example.com/category/4-way-to-change-mac-engine/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0#respond" target="_self">Leave a Comment</a></span> </p>
```

Above html will output

`June 3, 2017 by Albert Leave a Comment`

But I want to hide by Albert. The problem is I can't hide `by`as it's not wrapped within any html tag.

Comment: add css.  .entry-author-name{ display:none;}

Comment: That doesn't work, it still leaves the "by": `June 3, 2017 by Leave a Comment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visibility` can be overwritten on children elements. So we can customize just the root text node:

```
p.entry-meta{ visibility: hidden; }
p.entry-meta time, p.entry-meta span.entry-comments-link { visibility:visible; }
```

The problem is that visibility still occupies space:

```css
p.entry-meta{ visibility: hidden; }
p.entry-meta time, p.entry-meta span.entry-comments-link { visibility:visible; }
```

```html
<p class="entry-meta">
  <time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2017-06-03T02:58:22+00:00">June 3, 2017</time> by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a href="http://example.com/author/Albert/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author" target="_self"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Albert</span></a>
  </span>
  <span class="entry-comments-link"><a href="http://example.com/category/4-way-to-change-mac-engine/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0#respond" target="_self">Leave a Comment</a></span>  </p>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it still leaves the "by": June 3, 2017 by Leave a Comment

Comment: Hi Alan, run the code snippet, I believe the "by" is not visible anymore.

Comment: Just curious why the `by` is gone?

Comment: I understood that this is your question: Hide the "Author", but you were having problems hiding the "by", as it was not wrapped in any tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS to remove the text:

```css
    .entry-author-name { display: none; }
    p { font-size:0; }
    p > * {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
<p class="entry-meta">
  <time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2017-06-03T02:58:22+00:00">June 3, 2017</time> by <span class="entry-author" itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><a href="http://example.com/author/Albert/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0" class="entry-author-link" itemprop="url" rel="author" target="_self"><span class="entry-author-name" itemprop="name">Albert</span></a>
  </span>
 <span class="entry-comments-link"><a href="http://example.com/category/4-way-to-change-mac-engine/?customize_changeset_uuid=f30e84b8-4ed2-415a-9482-75fc161d62df&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-0#respond" target="_self">Leave a Comment</a></span>  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var el = document.querySelector(".entry-time").innerText;

    document.querySelector(".entry-meta").innerText=el;
```

[See](http://jsbin.com/fagodis/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript - select the paragraph DOM element and assign it to a variable, then remove the child nodes one at a time:

```
var entryMetas = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-meta");

for (var i = 0; i < entryMetas.length; i++){
    entryMetas[i].removeChild(entryMetas[i].childNodes[2]);
    entryMetas[i].removeChild(entryMetas[i].childNodes[1]);
}
```

If you're confined to CSS only, you can use Dorival's answer, but add an additional CSS rule to reduce the white space:

```
p.entry-meta span.entry-author-name{ display: inline-block; width: 0px; }
```